# I've got a js appear effect issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, scroll

This is js and there is 4 articles should appear one at a time when I scroll down, but it doesn't work after aticle no.2. what did I wrong?

```
function scrollAppear(){
var main = document.querySelector("main");
var art = main.querySelectorAll("article");

var artPos1 = art[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
var artPos2 = art[1].getBoundingClientRect().top;
var artPos3 = art[2].getBoundingClientRect().top;
var artPos4 = art[3].getBoundingClientRect().top;
var artPos5 = art[4].getBoundingClientRect().top;


var screenPos = window.innerHeight /1.3;


if (artPos1>600 && artPos1<700) {
    art[0].classList.add('appear');
}
else if (artPos2<500) {
    art[1].classList.add('appear');
}
else if (artPos3<800) {
    art[2].classList.add('appear');
}
else if (artPos4<600) {
    art[3].classList.add('appear');
}
else if (artPos5<600) {
    art[4].classList.add('appear');
}

}
window.addEventListener('scroll',scrollAppear);
```

Comment: Please add html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they all need to appear at the same spot, shouldn't the same condition work for each?

```js
if (artPos1>600 && artPos1<700) {
    art[0].classList.add('appear');
}
else if (artPos2>600 && artPos2<700) {
    art[1].classList.add('appear');
}
else if (artPos3>600 && artPos3<700) {
    art[2].classList.add('appear');
}
else if (artPos4>600 && artPos4<700) {
    art[3].classList.add('appear');
}
else if (artPos5>600 && artPos5<700) {
    art[4].classList.add('appear');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following jQuery example.

```js
function scrollAppear() {
  var main = $("#main");
  var art = $("article");

  var screenPos = $(window).scrollTop();

  art.each(function(i, el) {
    if (screenPos >= $(el).css("top").slice(0, -2) - 120) {
      $(el).fadeIn(100).addClass("appear");
    }
  });

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollAppear);
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  height: 2000px;
}

article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.red {
  background: #F00;
  top: 600px;
}

.orange {
  background: #F60;
  top: 700px;
}

.yellow {
  background: #FF0;
  top: 800px;
}

.green {
  background: #0F0;
  top: 900px;
}

.blue {
  background: #00F;
  top: 1000px;
}

.purple {
  background: #F0F;
  top: 1100px;
}

.appear {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <article class="red">
  </article>
  <article class="orange">
  </article>
  <article class="yellow">
  </article>
  <article class="green">
  </article>
  <article class="blue">
  </article>
  <article class="purple">
  </article>
</div>
```

You can use `.scrollTop()`:

> Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

Use `.each()` to iterate over each element and make it appear if scrolling has crossed the proper threshold on the screen.